# Laravel: How to group by users conversation correctly

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have like this database scheme:

```
Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('user_id')
        ->constrained()
        ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('sender_id');
    $table->foreign('sender_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->text('message');
    $table->foreignId('message_id')
        ->nullable()
        ->constrained()
        ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->tinyInteger('status')->default(0);
    $table->tinyInteger('view_status')->default(0);
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I tried get two user conversation like this:

```
$user = auth()->user();
$conversations = Message::where([
    ['user_id', $user->id],
])->orWhere([
    ['sender_id', $user->id],
])->groupBy('sender_id', 'user_id')->latest()->get();
```

But result is wrong and not grouping users conversation.

Here is simple data:

[image]

My query result currently:

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "user_id": 1,
        "sender_id": 2,
        "message": "How are you? ",
        "message_id": null,
        "status": 0,
        "view_status": 0,
        "created_at": "2021-08-17T08:18:03.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-08-17T08:18:03.000000Z",
        "user": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "John Doe"
        },
        "sender": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Nicolas Smith"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "user_id": 2,
        "sender_id": 1,
        "message": "Hello",
        "message_id": null,
        "status": 0,
        "view_status": 1,
        "created_at": "2021-08-17T07:25:18.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-08-17T08:19:09.000000Z",
        "user": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Nicolas Smith"
        },
        "sender": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "John Doe"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "user_id": 3,
        "sender_id": 2,
        "message": "Hi",
        "message_id": null,
        "status": 0,
        "view_status": 0,
        "created_at": "2021-08-16T23:44:17.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-08-16T23:44:17.000000Z",
        "user": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Richard"
        },
        "sender": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Nicolas Smith"
        }
    }
]
```

How I can group by correctly?

Comment: Do you want the rows pair (1,2) and (2,1) to be collapsed (considered as one group)? If so then group not by separate columns `(sender_id, user_id)` but by expression `(GREATEST(sender_id, user_id), LEAST(sender_id, user_id))`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, can you add an expected result?

Comment: What will it look like in a pure sql query? @Akina

Comment: I want group the rows pair (1,2) and (2,1) @Jerodev

Comment: *What will it look like in a pure sql query?* I post the code fragment which can be applied in pure SQL (in GROUP BY clause, and accordingly in the output list). And I don't know how this may be mapped to Laravel.

Comment: Thanks for answer @Akina I solved with this query in Laravel `->groupBy(\DB::raw('GREATEST(sender_id, user_id), LEAST(sender_id, user_id)'))`